# C# combined Find()

Tags: c#, linq, find

Is it possible to do something like below?

```
Interaction interaction=interactions.Find(i=>i.day==action.day,i=>i.scene==action.scene);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
IEnumerable<Interaction> matchingInteractions = interactions.Where(
    i => (i.day==action.day && i.scene == action.scene)
);
```

This uses LINQ's [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) which returns another `IEnumerable` of only the items that match the predicate function.

Alternatively, there is [`First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first.aspx), which returns the first item that matches the predicate.

```
Interaction firstInteraction = interactions.First(
    i => (i.day==action.day && i.scene == action.scene)
);
```

Finally, if you're certain there exists only one matching item, there is [`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.single.aspx).